# Making Haskell JSON ADT

Tags: json, haskell

I'm working on defining an algebraic data type (ADT) for JSON.

```
type Key = String

data Json = JObj Key JValue 
            | Arr [JValue] 
            deriving Show

data JValue = I Int 
              | F Float 
              | S String
              | B Bool
              | Json
              deriving Show
```

The above code compiles. But, I'm confused when trying to make the following JSON in my ADT:

`{"foo" : [1,2,3] }`

My attempt:

```
ghci> JObj "foo" (Arr [I 1, I 2, I 3])

<interactive>:101:13:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘JValue’ with actual type ‘Json’
    In the second argument of ‘JObj’, namely ‘(Arr [I 1, I 2, I 3])’
    In the expression: JObj "foo" (Arr [I 1, I 2, I 3])
```

I somewhat understand the error message, since `(Arr [I 1, I 2, I 3])` is, in fact, a `Json` instance.

But, I also defined `JValue` as `I Int | ... | Json`.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong for my above attempt.

Also - please don't correct my ADT otherwise as I'm working on it for practice!

Comment: So I can do `ghci> JObj "foo" Json | 
JObj "foo" Json`, but that's certainly not what I intended...

Comment: `JObj` takes a `Key` and a `JValue`. You have given it a `Key` and a `Json` (Arr is a constructor of `Json`). Without changing your ADT, you will not be able to represent what you want, because `JValue` simply has no constructors to represent an array. The `Json` constructor of `JValue` has *no relation* to the `Json` type.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong

```
data JValue = ...
            | Json
```

since it declares a value constructor having name `Json` carring no data at all, which is completely unrelated to the `Json` type. You want instead:

```
data JValue = ...
            | J Json
```

Your example then becomes:

```
JObj "foo" (J (Arr [I 1, I 2, I 3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing this for practice, the answer will be somewhat vague. However, I believe you likely have a small typo in the definition of your first Json constructor.

In particular, `Arr [JValue]` is a constructor to the type `Json`. There is no such constructor for `Key [JValue]`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with the current ADT. I will not correct your ADT but I have to point out the problems.

You probably want the values in a JObj to be of type Json. Then it is possible to use an Arr or a JObj as the value inside a JObj.

Another problem: Your JObj can hold only one key and one value. In JSON, an object contains multiple key-value entries.

If you let the Json type represent any JSON value I don't see the purpose of the JValue, though it would also work to let a JValue contain a Json but then you need a constructor with a parameter of type Json as pointed out by chi.

This would be more clear with an example but then it would ruin your excercise.